# increasing character limit of subitem in listview with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, subitem

I was wondering if its possible to increase the character limit of listview's subitems text.. there is a limitation of 259 characters..
any ideas would be appreciated..

regards,

Comment: There are at least three different listviews in .NET. Are you talking about WinForms, ASP.NET or WPF?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;321104 Says you can't increase it and recommend that you use a textbox to display it.

Comment: @Andrew Shepherd - I'm talkin about Winforms..

Comment: @Prix - is there any hack or something i can use to increase it. textbox definitely won't do what i need..

Comment: @ermac2014 yes a hack would be for you to break the object into multiple subitems, so you count your string size and divide it by 259 and create subitems to suply your string size

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET ListView, max number of characters, or maximum column width? Possible to override/expand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559704/net-listview-max-number-of-characters-or-maximum-column-width-possible-to-ove)

Comment: @Prix - hmmm.. not a bad idea.. thanks for the suggestion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some suggestions here. Unfortunately,  there is a limit on it which can't be exceeded.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/aad539a5-1b9f-4880-8b8e-59d4630706ab

1) You could try sub items to wrap the text. The item limit is 259 characters, so break the objects into multiple items.

2)  the only possible solution is to use your own or a third-party component which mimics a ListView but is not derived from it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be able to help you:

[.NET ListView, max number of characters, or maximum column width? Possible to override/expand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559704/net-listview-max-number-of-characters-or-maximum-column-width-possible-to-ove)

Here's the code specifically to help you create your own listview:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView()
    {
        OwnerDraw = true;
        DrawItem += new DrawListViewItemEventHandler(MyListView_DrawItem);
    }

    private void MyListView_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font, 
                                    new SolidBrush(e.Item.ForeColor), e.Bounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: so that means i need to draw the whole control from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if [objectlistview](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) supports this.